# Exclude certain subdomains from accessing session in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3.1, subdomain

When using `:domain => :all` on sessions in 3.1 is it possible to exclude certain subdomains? I'm using a subdomain CDN with s3 bucket and would like to make it cookie-free when requesting images.